# data is not inserting into mongodb using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

hello I am new to nodejs and trying to inserting data in mongodb but its not inserting, and no error is showing, and on page submit it says "Cannot POST /crud", any refrence or suggestion to resolve it (remember no error is showing)

schema(Crud.js):

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/node_web', {useNewUrlParser: true});

   var crudSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      crud_name: {
         type: String
      },
      crud_email: {
         type: String
      },
      crud_mobile: {
         type: String
      }
  });

  mongoose.model('Crud', crudSchema );
```

create.ejs:

```
   <form method="POST" action="/crud">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="crud_name" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Enter your name">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="crud_email" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Enter your email">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress">Mobile</label>
        <input type="number" name="crud_mobile" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Enter your mobile">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

controller:

```
    const express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Crud = mongoose.model('Crud');

    router.get('/',(req, res) => {
      res.render("crud", {crud : new Crud(), newCrud : true});
    });

    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
       if (true)
          insertRecord(req, res);
    });

    function insertRecord(req, res) {
        var crud = new Crud();
        crud.crud_name = req.body.crud_name;
        crud.crud_email = req.body.crud_email;
        crud.crud_mobile = req.body.crud_mobile;
        // Save methods
        crud.save((err, doc) => {
          if (!err)
             res.redirect('crud');
          else {
            console.log('Error during record insertions : ' + err);
          }
      });  
    }
```

db is successfully connected:

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/node_web', {useNewUrlParser: true});

  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
  db.once('open', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
     console.log('Successfully connected');
  });
```

Comment: where is your node.js code ? i am not sure but is it possible to request model file to enter data in database .
u have to create route that will point to a function and that will call ur schema which will send data please clear me about this if i am wrong

Comment: @sayalok sorry I forgot about adding controller

Comment: @pro U need to pass the saving object to model constructor like `var crud = new Crud({a:req.body.a, b:req.body.b})` and the route definition is also incorrect, it should be `router.post('/crud')`

Comment: @ambianBeing sory to say that can u plz provide me a proper ans coz m new to it and don't know more

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should get the post request by specifying the URL as,

```js
router.post('/crud', (req, res) => {
// Rest of the method..

});
```

Comment: still same error, now my code is router.post('/crud', (req, res) => {
     function insertRecord(req, res) {
 var crud = new Crud();
 crud.crud_name = req.body.crud_name;
 crud.crud_email = req.body.crud_email;
 crud.crud_mobile = req.body.crud_mobile;
    // Save methods
 crud.save((err, doc) => {
  if (!err)
    res.redirect('crud');
  else {
   console.log('Error during record insertions : ' + err);
  }
 });
}
});

Comment: it only says "Cannot POST /crud", no error in console.log

Comment: @pro Did you export your route from the controller file like this - ```module.exports = router;```

Comment: I wrote this at the end of file

Comment: @pro In your main app.js file did you use the route ```var crud = require('<location _of_controller.js');

app.use('/crud', crud);```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198645/discussion-between-pro-and-sasuke-uchiha).

Comment: yes, const crudController = require('./controllers/crudController');

Comment: now it says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'crud_name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

create a app.js file and add it there

```
const crudRoutes = require('./crudRoutes');
app.use('/crud',crudRoutes);
```

create a route file and do the following

```
const express = require('express');
const crudController = require('./crudController')
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/crud', crudController.crud_process)
module.exports = router
```

in controller file

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const Crud = require('./crudModel') // ur schema file
 exports.crud_process = (req, res, next) => {
    // ur query 
  })
```

for complete details u can check one of my project here i did it for study purpose
[nodejsapiproject](https://github.com/sayalok/noderestApi)

Comment: in app.js file I hv already added require('./models/Crud');    const crudController = require('./controllers/crudController');

Comment: try a console in ur conroller and chk if u get the req there

Comment: nthing is coming in console I write it : console.log(req.body);

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Crud = mongoose.model('Crud');

    router.get('/',(req, res) => {
      res.render("crud", {crud : new Crud(), newCrud : true});
    });

    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
       if (true)
          insertRecord(req, res);
    });

    function insertRecord(req, res) {
        var crud = new Crud({
          crud_name:req.body.crud_name,
          crud_email : req.body.crud_email,
          crud_mobile : req.body.crud_mobile
});

        // Save methods
        crud.save((err, doc) => {
          if (!err)
             res.redirect('crud');
          else {
            console.log('Error during record insertions : ' + err);
          }
      });  
    }
```

Comment: try some thing like this. so you get it helpfull for you